# How to Parse Any Datetime format to yyyy-MM-dd in java

Tags: java, date-formatting

I have a date field that is populated dynamically, and I need that field in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`

For a input date of format `1994-08-01 14:37:44` this is giving a Exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1994-08-01 14:37:44' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

This is one of the many other ways I tried `LocalDateTime.parse("1994-08-01 14:37:44",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(yyyy-MM-dd));`

Is there a way to convert all date/datetime to yyyy-MM-dd format?

please help

Thanks

Comment: `LocalDateTime` needs a time component to be able to parse a string

Comment: I have tried `LocalDate` but it works for date coming in `yyyy-MM-dd` format but fails for datetime input.

Comment: Your input is a date/time value.  The formatter you are using only takes into consideration the date part and `LocalDateTime` requires both.  Use a formatter for the whole string, `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, you can then format the value any way you want - Start with what you have and work towards what you want.

Comment: The crux of all these answers: there are _two different formats_ you need to worry about. You need to worry about the *input format* (that's the one that goes into `LocalDateTime.parse(...)`), and then once you have a proper object, you can create a string it using an *output format* (passing it into `yourLocalDateTime.format(...)`). But no, there is not one single way to "convert all date/datetime". You need to begin with some idea about the structure of your input in order to handle it.

Comment: Is your field always in `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format? If you don’t know the format, you generally cannot parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. You can extract the `LocalDate` part.

```
LocalDate ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("1994-08-01 14:37:44",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

Prints

```
1994-08-01
```

Comment: I need just the Date part of it in the format yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: IMHO, I wouldn't rely on the `toString` representation of the object, it might change between locales or implementations - just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer It took me a few seconds to realize what you were saying.  I agree.  Altered the answer accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: It’s well documented what `LocalDate.toString()` returns, so that shouldn’t change. Whether you want to rely on it is probably more a matter of taste.

Comment: No need for `toLocalDate()`. As long as you're using the `DateTimeFormatter` class instead of `toString()`, the original `LocalDateTime` object will work just fine. Output should be prepared at output time, when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have a date and time component but you're only using a date format to parse it to a `LocalDateTime` value, this will fail because `LocalDateTime` needs the time component in order to work

Start by parsing the full text

```
String input = "1994-08-01 14:37:44";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Then use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format it the way you want

```
String formatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(ldt);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

which prints

```
1994-08-01
```

Depending on your needs, you could also convert the `LocalDateTime` value to a `LocalDate` and format it, it's the same result, but you might have need of the `LocalDate` for other things, who knows...

```
String formatted = ldt.toLocalDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: I don't think it's correct that "`LocalDateTime` needs the time component in order to work". The reason the parse fails is that the input does not match the explicit format provided.

Comment: @AndrewF False and true. `LocalDateTIme` certainly needs a time component. You are correct that the OP’s parsing failed because of format mismatch. The following would not have worked either because the time componenet is missing: `LocalDateTime.parse("1994-08-01",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(yyyy-MM-dd))`.